# C# .Net 3.5 Code to replace a file extension using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I've written this very simple function to replace a file extension using LINQ in C#.NET 3.5 however I have a feeling that there's a more elegant way to do this. (I'm not committed to using LINQ here - just looking for a more elegant approach.) Ideas?

```
    private string ReplaceFileExtension(string fileName, string newExtension)
    {
        string[] dotSplit = fileName.Split('.');
        return String.Join(".", dotSplit.Take(dotSplit.Length - 1).ToArray()) + "." + newExtension;
    }
```

(I'm aware of the fact that this won't work if the original file name doesn't have a dot.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's very easy... just use [System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx)